# Execute a javascript code only on refreshing a page after 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I have a requirement where a java script code is there which makes a ajax call and save the user log in database on page load. But the problem is that every time when the user refresh the page the code is getting executed. I want to execute the statement only if the page is refreshed after 10 seconds not on every page refresh. I have to stop executing the code flow if the page is refreshed before 10 seconds.

Comment: You have to store last time it was called...in cookie or localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code executes all 10 seconds (or longer), triggered by a page reload:

You need to store the time (in localStorage), on reload check if now is later than stored time+ 10 seconds:

```
function store(){
//store time:
now=new Date().getTime();
localStorage.setItem("stored",now);
//your password storing
}

window.onload=function(){
now=new Date.getTime();
if(!localStorage.getItem("stored")){
//no time stored, so lets store
store();
return;
}
last=localStorage.getItem("stored");
//if now is later than last+10seconds
if(now>last+1000*60*10){
store();
}
}
```

Comment: youre welcome. please mark it as answer, trough pressing the green tick...

Answer (score 0):

Can you set cookies? Set the cookie value to current path, on redirect check the cookie value against the current URL. When it matches (so it is a refresh) you can trigger your 10 sec delay by

```
Logging = setTimout(function() {
    Alert("10 seconds passed");
    }, 10 * 1000);
```

To clear the timeout, use

```
clearTimeout(Logging)
```